# Behavior of the expected distance from a random point sampled from an centrally symmetric distribution

Tags: probability, computational-geometry

Given an probability distribution $\mathcal{P}$ over points, that is centrally symmetric about the origin such that $\mathcal{P}(x) = \mathcal{P}(-x)$, does the expected distance of a random point, $x\in\mathcal{P}$, to a fixed point, say $Q$, on an arbitrarily chosen ray from the origin increase *monotonically* as the distance (along the ray) of Q from origin increases?

I want to use the above statement as part of a larger proof if true. The guarantee of *monotonicity* is important and I'm wondering if this is already a known result.

Thanks!

Edit: I corrected my earlier post where I mistakenly mentioned that the distance *fell off*, instead of *increased* monotonically.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! You are right and my apologies for what was, in fact, an error. I fixed it now to convey what I actually had in mind--- that the expected distance increases monotonically.

Comment: I've made the change. Thanks for the feedback!